# Elements don't show up on initial render, only after state changes

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I started a little books app project in react with multiple pages. On the Homepage at the bottom, i want to display some New York Times Bestseller books. For this project i'm mainly using the Google Books API, but for my Bestsellers Section, i first run a function which gets a list of the current Betsellers from the New York Times Books API and filters out the ISBN numbers, then i run a function which loops over each number and gets data from the Google Books API and saves it in state.

Here is my `Context` file with state `bestseller` and the two functions:

```
import React, { createContext, useState } from "react"
const Context = createContext()

function ContextProvider(props) {
  const [bestSeller, setBestSeller] = useState([])
  const [theme, setTheme] = useState(
    () => JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("theme")) || "light"
  )

  async function getBestSellerIsbns() {
    try {
      const url = `https://api.nytimes.com/svc/books/v3/lists/current/hardcover-fiction.json?&api-key=${NYT_API_KEY}`
      const response = await fetch(url)
      const data = await response.json()
      const isbns = data.results.books.map(book => book.primary_isbn10)
      getBooksWithIsbn(isbns)

    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error)
    }
  }

  function getBooksWithIsbn(isbnList) {
      let arr = [];
      for (let isbn of isbnList) {
        fetch(`https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=isbn:${isbn}&printType=books`)
          .then((res) => res.json())
          .then((data) => {
            arr.push(data.items[0])
          })
      }
      setBestSeller(arr)
  }

  function changeTheme() {
    setTheme(prevTheme => prevTheme === "light" ? "dark" : "light")
  }

  return (
    <Context.Provider
      value={{
        bestSeller,
        changeTheme,
        getBestSellerIsbns
      }}
    >
      {props.children}
    </Context.Provider>
  )
}
```

`bestSeller` and `getBestSellerIsbns` get passed down to the `Homepage`:

```
const HomePage = () => {
  const { bestSeller, getBestSellerIsbns} = useContext(Context)
  
  useEffect(() => {
    getBestSellerIsbns()
  }, [])

  const bestSellerElements = bestSeller.map(best => (
    <BestsellerEl key={best.id} best={best}/>
  ))

  return (
    <div className="homepage-container">
      <div className="bottom-container">
        <div className="container-title">
          <h1>New York Times Bestsellers:</h1>
        </div>
        <div classname="bestseller-div">
          {bestSellerElements}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

And `changeTheme` gets passed down to `Navbar`:

```
const Navbar = () => {
  const {changeTheme} = useContext(Context)

  return (
    <div className="navbar">
      <div className="nav-elements">
        <label className="switch">
          <input type="checkbox" onClick={changeTheme} />
          <span className="slider"></span>
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

On the inital render `bestSellerElements` doesn't get displayed, when i navigate to a different page through the `navbar` and then come back to `Homepage` the Elements show up just for a second and then disappear again, but weirdly enough, when i change the state of `theme` the `bestSellerElements` appear and stay like that until i refresh the page again.

Turning the `getBooksWithIsbn` function into an async/await function solved the displaying issues, but it takes about 5 seconds before the elements show up, is there a way to to reduce that? Other than that, thank you guys for your help.

```
async function getBooksWithIsbn(isbnList) {
    try {
      let arr = []
      for(let isbn of isbnList) {
        const url = `https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=isbn:${isbn}&printType=books`
        const response = await fetch(url)
        const data = await response.json()
        arr.push(data.items[0])
      }
      setBestSeller(arr)
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error)
    }
  }
```

Comment: My first guess is that `isbnList` is empty

Comment: Is this updated code? I don't see getBestSellerIsbns function passed in value for Provider. Use async await for getBooksWithIsbn as well.

Comment: Seems like state is getting set before you get to fetch the books. You need to await the fetch in that for of loop

Comment: It taking 5 seconds before showing elements is just the async functing taking time to fetch the data from the server. The standard way is to show a loading animation during the fetching process.